# vmc push app reports "Failed to Start" but the app IS running

Tags: cloud-foundry

We have created our own, internal, multi-node cloud foundry with BOSH.  When I push a simple sinatra app, it goes through all of the steps showing the following couple of lines:

```
Uploading hello... OK
Starting hello... OK
Checking hello... GAVE UP
Application failed to start.
```

(last two lines take a while to finish writing, of course)

But when I try to hit the app URL, hello.mycloud.example.com, everything works fine.  That is, the application is, in fact, running.  I looked at the logs on the dea and sure enough, they report that the app has started and that the system has been notified.

```
[2012-12-20 20:08:45.813061] dea - pid=24441 tid=40fc fid=0c65   INFO -- Starting up instance (name=hellocornelia app_id=1 instance=1e4cae7a70078687753ebc7d116de550 index=0) on port:62642
[2012-12-20 20:08:45.835886] dea - pid=24441 tid=40fc fid=47ea   INFO -- Starting up instance (name=hellocornelia app_id=1 instance=d1e1b77335f23d3ce1fe5e24caf85ed5 index=1) on port:62047
[2012-12-20 20:08:46.369563] dea - pid=24441 tid=40fc fid=23e8   INFO -- Instance (name=hellocornelia app_id=1 instance=1e4cae7a70078687753ebc7d116de550 index=0) is ready for connections, notifying system of status
[2012-12-20 20:08:46.370488] dea - pid=24441 tid=40fc fid=23e8   INFO -- Instance (name=hellocornelia app_id=1 instance=d1e1b77335f23d3ce1fe5e24caf85ed5 index=1) is ready for connections, notifying system of status
[2012-12-20 20:08:46.873075] dea - pid=24441 tid=40fc fid=23e8   INFO -- PID:22404 assigned to droplet instance: (name=hellocornelia app_id=1 instance=1e4cae7a70078687753ebc7d116de550 index=0)
[2012-12-20 20:08:46.873591] dea - pid=24441 tid=40fc fid=23e8   INFO -- PID:22410 assigned to droplet instance: (name=hellocornelia app_id=1 instance=d1e1b77335f23d3ce1fe5e24caf85ed5 index=1)
```

running a vmc apps with trace turned on shows:

```
{
"name": "hello",
"staging": {
  "model": "sinatra",
  "stack": "ruby18"
},
"uris": [
  "hello.cloudad.sccf.lab.emc.com"
],
"instances": 1,
"runningInstances": 0,
"resources": {
  "memory": 128,
  "disk": 2048,
  "fds": 256
},
"state": "STARTED",
"services": [

],
"version": "966c1f76a126696d09db9f49405f42130f72cbc3-1",
"env": [

],
"meta": {
  "debug": null,
  "console": null,
  "version": 3,
  "created": 1356035779
}
}
]
<<<
... OK
name    status   usage      runtime   url
hello   0%       1 x 128M   ruby18    hello.cloudad.sccf.lab.emc.com
```

which is to be expected since the system doesn't know the app is running.  I've checked in the cloud controller and health manager logs and cannot seem to find any indication of where things are failing.  Any hints?

Thanks.

Comment: Two OSS sites that could be helpful for this type of question are, https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/vcap-dev and the bosh users site, https://groups.google.com/a/cloudfoundry.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/bosh-users

Answer (score 1):

I would check your health manager. The health manager log would be helpful. It might not even be running. Do check your vm status via

```
bosh vms
```

And if your health manager is running, I would ssh into it and check the logs located in the /var/vcap/sys location

```
bosh ssh <component-name> <index>
```

i.e.

```
 bosh ssh health_manager 0
```

I would say most likely there is a issue with your health manager. Since all is working but you are not seeing it in the client (vmc)